# How to get website information using requests_html?

Tags: python, python-requests

The url I want to visit is `https://dealer.autohome.com.cn/2065423/`

The code I wrote is:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = r'https://dealer.autohome.com.cn/2065423/'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'allagency-cont'})
```

In the `allagency-cont` tag, the information I want but missed is:

```
<div class="telphone">
<div title="当前商家咨询电话数量接通服务比例">
    电话接听率：100%
</div>
<div class="fn-clear">
    <div class="phone-name">
        15天订单量：
    </div>
    <div title="当前商家15天内订单量数量" class="progress">
        <span style="width:20%;" class="progress-value"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript has not been executed. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: If the element you want to capture is rendered with JavaScript, then you should use `selenium` instead of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Can we use the package `requests_html`?